# Access: Ole Server Fails when calling events code

Tags: forms, vba, events, ms-access-2013

Working with forms in MS Access 2013, I had to change form names but after that Ole Server fails trying to find the code related with the events.

I could restore some of the fails but only with Macro (those which were related with form names).

A failure its produced when I use the event Change() on a ComboBox element. It isn't related with vba code.

How could I resolve this?

Comment: I think you are saying you changed the name of one of your forms in Access, and now get an error? If not VBA code, then the problem could lie in a Macro, or a Form object property (i.e. field validation), a query.... etc. What have you done to try and locate? What action causes the error?

Comment: Have you backed-up, compacted & repaired and decompiled?

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn That's exactly what I mean, however, I solved it duplicating that form, removing original and renaming the duplicated one. Then it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @Remou Yes, I tried that but didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: You can either do the dirty work yourself and examine all objects looking for where the old form name is mentioned, or you may want to try this http://www.accessdependencychecker.com/ which does the work for you. You install as an 'Add-In', then it allows you to search for anything you want and it will tell you every place there is a reference. I stumbled across it a few months ago -- but wish I had it 10 years ago!

Comment: Thank you very much @WayneG.Dunn! I will download it right now just in case :D